# How to convert the prediction of pytorch into normal text

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a PyTorch model and i am doing prediction on it. After doing prediction i am getting the output as

```
tensor([[-3.4333]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

But i need it as normal integer `-3.4333`. How can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`.item`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html) on your tensor to convert it to a standard python number.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value inside a tensor call: `tensor.item()`

Ex:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1.0])
>>> x.item()
1.0
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html